# Ionic offline sync with own SQL server

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, synchronization, loopbackjs, offline-caching

I am making an app with Ionic framework. I must work offline and when connection comes back, sync with server data. I found a lot of solutions including pouchDB (CouchDB), or hosted solutions like Firebase, Parse, etc.

But my requirements are:
 1. Work with a Relational SQL database (Companies, Clients, Invoices, Products...)
 2. App must synchronize with NodeJS + PostgreSQL hosted in Company server.

I tried loopback, but I am not able to make it work at client side as I told in their google group: [LoopbackJS Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/Ms1FogAA9Jk).

So, anyone know another good solution for offline caching and sync ionic mobile app with a server, working with these requirements?

Comment: Your SQL datbase (Clients ...) is read-only and your write to the PostgreSQL database ?

Comment: It is a 4way data-binding implementation, both databases have read and write permissions. You can see in [that image](http://admin.frontmag.no/sites/default/files/blank_flowchart_-_new_page_2.png) how works.

The app works with device database.If there is Internet connection, pull data from server on reads, and write local database and then replicates to server database on writes.

If there is no connection,read from local database data from previous reads,and write to local,when there is online, push writes to server.

Anyways, I found relational-pouchdb project and now I'm working with it.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same case

Comment: @MissakBoyajian, I did not. I moved to n noSQL solution, CouchDB in server and PouchDB in the mobile app. The sync works out of the box.